# How do I execute a second command with the .NET Oracle connection?

Tags: .net, oracle, powershell

I am using the Oracle .NET drivers through Powershell. I am able to execute one query, but when I try to execute a second one, no results are returned.

Can anyone explain what is happening, and how to get the second query to execute?

Thanks

```
$c = New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection($connectionString)
$c.open()

# THIS WORKS
$cmd = $c.CreateCommand()
$cmd.CommandText = "select * from TABLE where ID = 'MyID55'"
$reader = $cmd.ExecuteReader()
while ($reader.Read()) {
    for($i -eq 0; $i -lt $reader.FieldCount; $i++){
        $v = $reader.GetValue($i)
        if($v -ne ([System.DBNull]::Value)){
            "$($reader.GetName($i)): $v"
        }
    }
}
$reader.close()

# THIS RUNS, BUT DOESN'T RETURN VALUES
$cmd = $c.CreateCommand()
$cmd.CommandText = "select * from TABLE2 where ID = 'MyID55'"
$reader = $cmd.ExecuteReader()
while ($reader.Read()) {
    for($i -eq 0; $i -lt $reader.FieldCount; $i++){
        $v = $reader.GetValue($i)
        if($v -ne ([System.DBNull]::Value)){
            "$($reader.GetName($i)): $v"
        }
    }
}

$c.close()
$c.dispose()
```

Comment: Do you need to call the `Close` method on the first `$reader` before executing the second command?

Comment: No records found in `select * from TABLE2 where ID = 'MyID55'`??

Comment: I tried calling close() on the reader, and also closing and disposing the other objects also.

Comment: There are records found, and they show if I don't run the first block of code.